# What is the best solution to fix defects after migrating to Alamofire 4 and Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I convert my project code to Swift 3. I used heavily Alamofire. I updated it to  Almofire 4, but I faced many errors related the changing in the methods names and the order of the parameters.

What is the best solution to fix all these issues?

Comment: Please ask specific question. Where you stuck!?

Comment: I meant what is the best solution to fix all these issues?

Comment: set Alamofire 4  1build settings legacy version to true1 which will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution my opinion after migration to Alamofire 4 and Swift3:
Manually rename methods and reoprder parameters as a new style.

Each error I searched on the correct name and parameters in [this guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md) and in [the Alamofire main](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) page.